# Gazebo 1.5 crash on startup, InvalidNameException

Tags: gazebo-1.5, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had some problems with old sdf files, I got warnings with the default empty_world so I now use a custom empty world.

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
$ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Would these files be fixed if I reinstall ROS Groovy?

But the InvalidNameException persists, what could cause this?

```
lennart@Flaptop:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials$ roslaunch beginner_tutorials empty_sdf.launch 
... logging to /home/lennart/.ros/log/9cb9bd36-f6d5-11e2-b449-0025b3bf3892/roslaunch-Flaptop-8479.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Flaptop:33673/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8494]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 9cb9bd36-f6d5-11e2-b449-0025b3bf3892
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8507]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [8521]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [8526]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
  what():  Character [] at element [8] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [gazeboeb].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 8521, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/lennart/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/worlds/empty_sdf.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/lennart/.ros/log/9cb9bd36-f6d5-11e2-b449-0025b3bf3892/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/lennart/.ros/log/9cb9bd36-f6d5-11e2-b449-0025b3bf3892/gazebo-2*.log
```

The launch file:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="throttled" default="false"/>

  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <group if="$(arg use_sim_time)">
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </group>


  <!-- start empty world -->
  <group if="$(arg paused)">
    <group if="$(arg throttled)">
      <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find beginner_tutorials)/worlds/empty_throttled.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    </group>
    <group unless="$(arg throttled)">
      <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find beginner_tutorials)/worlds/empty_sdf.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    </group>
  </group>
  <group unless="$(arg paused)">
    <group if="$(arg throttled)">
      <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find beginner_tutorials)/worlds/empty_throttled.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    </group>
    <group unless="$(arg throttled)">
      <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find beginner_tutorials)/worlds/empty_sdf.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    </group>
  </group>

  <!-- start gui -->
  <group if="$(arg gui)">
    <node name="gazebogui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3935/gazebo-1.5-crash-on-startup,-invalidnameexception/) by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-30**:
I am not quite sure I understand the problem. Did you already run gzsdf convert? you don't have to reinstall ROS to convert sdf files to the new version, just running gzsdf convert should be enough.

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-07-30**:
I did already converted the file (but it is a bit unhandy as the files are installed under /opt and you need root rights to convert them). The problem now is the ros::InvalidNameException' which makes Gazebo crash. I cannot load a world in Gazebo as it crashes constantly.

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-30**:
Then I am not sure why. Maybe this helps?http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1126/after-updating-to-gazebo-13-under-ros-groovy-i-get/

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-30**:
Then I am not sure why. Maybe this helps? http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1126/after-updating-to-gazebo-13-under-ros-groovy-i-get/

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/866/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-09**:
Hi, did you ever find a solution? I have the same `InvalidNameException` for `empty_world` and an SDF parsing error similar to yours with `simple_world` (or any other world with objects in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you were working on a 32-bit OS, then I believe that is your issue. I have the same issue on all the 32-bit machines in my lab, but not the 64-bit ones. It is also not a problem in later versions of Gazebo; only the one needed by Groovy (1.5).

---

Originally posted by [Neil Traft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/866/neil-traft/) with karma: 18 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0